# Number Theory: Möbius Function

Tags: number-theory, mobius-function

### Background

> [image]

**Definition:**

If $S$ with partial order ≤ is locally finite with minimal element, then the generalized Möbius function $\mu$: S $\times$ S $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{N}$ by
(a) $\forall$ s $\in$S, $\mu$ (s, s)=1
(b) for r< s, $\mu$ (r, s) = - $\sum_{t \in [r, s) } μ(r, t)$\

**Theorem to be proved:**

Let S $\neq$ ∅ and define if and only if a | b, then a ≤ b. If {d, n}$\mathbb{Z}$, μ(d, n)= $\frac{n}{d}$

**Source:**

Number Theory with Applications (James A. Anderson, James M. Bell)

### My Question

Sorry that I have tried to prove this theorem for many times but I fail. Could somebody help me?

Comment: Check your definition of $\mu(r,s)$ again

Comment: Sorry that I have typed the definition wrongly. I have edited it. (but I have used the correct definition before, but still have no clue how to prove this) (Here is the def. provided in the textbook, in case I still typed wrongly https://imgur.com/a/IrQWT6v)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid any possible confusion, I’ll use $\mu'$ for the number theoretic function.

You can do it by induction on $n$. Assume that

$$\mu(d,m)=\mu'\left(\frac{m}d\right)$$

whenever $1\le d\mid m<n$, and let $1\le d\mid n$. If $d=n$, we have

$$\mu(d,n)=\mu(n,n)=1=\mu'(1)=\mu'\left(\frac{n}d\right)\,,$$

so assume that $d<n$.

Let $\prod_{k=1}^\ell p_k^{\alpha_k}$ be the prime factorization of $\frac{n}d$, where each $\alpha_k\ge 1$. then $m\in[d,n)$ iff $\frac{m}d=\prod_{k\in S}p_k^{\beta_k}$, where $S\subseteq\{1,\ldots,\ell\}$, $1\le\beta_k\le\alpha_k$ for $k\in S$, and either $S\ne\{1,\ldots,\ell\}$, or there is a $k\in S$ such that $\beta_k<\alpha_k$.

Suppose first that $\alpha_k=1$ for $k=1,\ldots,\ell$, so that $\mu'\left(\frac{n}d\right)=(-1)^\ell$. Then $m\in[d,n)$ iff there is an $S\subsetneqq\{1,\ldots,\ell\}$ such that $\frac{m}d=\prod_{k\in S}p_k$, and therefore

$$\begin{align*}
\mu(d,n)&=-\sum_{m\in[d,n)}\mu(d,m)\\
&=-\sum_{m\in[d,n)}\mu'\left(\frac{m}d\right)\\
&=-\sum_{S\subsetneqq\{1,\ldots,\ell\}}(-1)^{|S|}\\
&\overset{(1)}=-\sum_{k=0}^{\ell-1}(-1)^k\binom{\ell}k\\
&\overset{(2)}=-\left((1-1)^\ell-(-1)^\ell\right)\\
&\overset{(3)}=(-1)^\ell\\
&=\mu'\left(\frac{n}d\right)\,.
\end{align*}$$

Here $(1)$ is because $\{1,\ldots,\ell\}$ has $\binom{\ell}k$ subsets of cardinality $k$, $(2)$ follows from the binomial theorem, and $(3)$ holds because $0^\ell=0$, since $\ell\ge 1$.

The other possibility is that $\alpha_k>1$ for some $k\in\{1,\ldots,\ell\}$, so that $\mu'\left(\frac{n}d\right)=0$. See if you can carry out the induction step in this case: the computation is actually very similar to the one that I just did, though for some $m\in[d,n)$ you’ll have $\mu'\left(\frac{m}d\right)=0$.

**Added:** If $\alpha_k>1$ for some $k\in\{1,\ldots,\ell\}$, we have to split the $m\in[d,n)$ into those that will actually contribute to $\mu(d,n)$ and those that contribute $0$. For each $m\in[d,n)$ let $\frac{m}d=\prod_{k=1}^\ell p_k^{\beta_k(m)}$, where $0\le\beta_k(m)\le\alpha_k$ for each $k\in\{1,\ldots,\ell\}$. Let

$$S_m=\{k\in\{1,\ldots,\ell\}:\beta_k(m)=1\}$$

and

$$T_m=\{k\in\{1,\ldots,\ell\}:\beta_k(m)>1\}\,.$$

If $T_m\ne\varnothing$, then $\mu(d,m)=\mu'\left(\frac{m}d\right)=0$. Moreover, for each $S\subseteq\{1,\ldots,\ell\}$ there is exactly one $m\in[d,n)$ such that $S_m=S$ and $T_m=\varnothing$, and each of these is a **proper** divisor of $n$, so

$$\begin{align*}
\mu(d,n)&=-\sum_{m\in[d,n)}\mu(d,m)\\
&=-\sum_{m\in[d,n)}\mu'\left(\frac{m}d\right)\\
&=-\sum_{\substack{m\in[d,n)\\T_m=\varnothing}}\mu'\left(\frac{m}d\right)\\
&=-\sum_{S\subseteq\{1,\ldots,\ell\}}(-1)^{|S|}\\
&=-\sum_{k=0}^\ell(-1)^k\binom{\ell}k\\
&=-(1-1)^\ell\\
&=0\\
&=\mu'\left(\frac{n}d\right)\,.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Is the proof of another possibility like this? (Sorry that I have not learnt LaTeX yet. I would learn it soon) https://imgur.com/a/H6XS4By

Comment: @KelvinChan: It’s a bit more complicated than that. It’s more like what I did, except that $\mu'\left(\frac{m}d\right)=0$ for some of the $m\in[d,n)$ and therefore contribute nothing to $\mu(d,n)$. You have to figure out exactly which values of $m$ do contribute and show that their contributions sum to $0$.

Comment: Here is what I got so far, but I am unsure about the last step. https://imgur.com/a/Y4M80tN

Comment: I've tried once more and here's proof that is more reasonable than before https://imgur.com/a/5AKVSSG

Comment: @KelvinChan: In the second one you’re confusing members of $[d,n)$ with subscripts on the prime factors of $\frac{n}d$. In the first one you have $s$ representing both a set of indices and an index. With the notation in my answer, what you need to observe is that if some $\beta_k>1$, then $\mu'\left(\frac{m}d\right)=0$, so we need only consider those $m$ for which $\beta_k=1$ for all $k\in S$. Then the calculation is just like mine, except that we have to include the case $S=\{1,\ldots,\ell\}$, since $d\prod_{k=1}^\ell p_k<n$ now (because at least one $\alpha_k>1$).

Comment: Like this? https://imgur.com/gByOFWC

Comment: @KelvinChan: It’s close, but it doesn’t quite work as written. The problem is that you’re not dealing with a fixed set of exponents $\beta_k$: each $m\in[d,n)$ has its own set, so there is no fixed partition of the exponents into those that are $1$ and those that are greater than $1$. I would begin by observing that $m\in[d,n)$ iff there are disjoint $S_m,T_m\subseteq\{1,\ldots,\ell\}$ such that $\frac{m}d=\prod_{k\in S_m\cup T_m}p_k^{\beta_k}$, $\beta_k=1$ for $k\in S_m$, and $\beta_k>1$ for $k\in T_m$. If $T_m\ne\varnothing$, then $\mu(d,m)=-\mu'\left(\frac{m}d\right)=0$, which ...

Comment: ... contribute nothing to $\mu(d,n)$, and we can sum over those $m\in[d,n)$ such that $T_m=\varnothing$. Show that these are in $1$-$1$ correspondence with **all** subsets of $\{1,\ldots,\ell\}$, and you’re home free.

Comment: Does it mean that I need to use set instead? (https://imgur.com/a/bFDKOHW) (The red words indicate where I have corrected)

Comment: @KelvinChan: You still have the same problem at the beginning. Each $m\in[d,n)$ has a different set of exponents $\beta_k$; there is no fixed set $\{\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_\ell\}$ that applies to every $m$. We really ought to say that for each $m\in[d,n)$ there are disjoint $S_m,T_m\subseteq\{1,\ldots,\ell\}$ and positive integers $\beta_k\color{red}{(m)}$ for $k\in S_m\cup T_m$ such that $\beta_k(m)=1$ for $k\in S_m$, and $\beta_k(m)>1$ for $k\in T_m$.

Comment: like this? https://imgur.com/a/YkwWp2n

Comment: @KelvinChan: You’re still making the same mistake, albeit in a subtler form. You **cannot** combine the sets $S_m$ into a single set $S$ and the sets $T_m$ into a single set $T$; **must** treat each $m\in[d,n)$ **separately**. And later on $m$ is **not** in $S\cup T$: your $S$ and $T$ are subsets of $\{1,\ldots,\ell\}$, not of $[d,n)$. And the dummy variable $x$ in the definitions of $S_m$ and $T_m$ should be $k$. I can’t get to it right away, but I’ll try to add it to the answer sometime in the next few hours.

Comment: @KelvinChan: I got to it sooner than I thought I could.